# How to solve this error Undefined index: password in on line

Tags: php

**Undefined index: password in on line**

: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd4/628/18415628/public_html/Kunj/admin/index.php:8) in on line

: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd4/628/18415628/public_html/Kunj/admin/index.php:8) in on line

Not Access!

**This error comes from this code**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('functions.php');
require_once('dbconnection.php');
require_once('includes/init.php');
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$admin_data = get_admin($conn, $password);
if ($password != $admin_data['password']) {
    header('location: login.php');
```

Comment: Make sure the session value is definitely set before you try to use it

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
```

to

```
if(isset($_SESSION['password'])){
  $password = $_SESSION['password'];
}else{
  $password = '';
}
```